# Ember {{#each}} shows previously deleted records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

I've been fighting a bug in an app I'm working on. I have created a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wavudakibi/3/edit?html,js,output) to illustrate it and these are the steps you should take to reproduce it:

1. Click on the link that says "*New Rule Set*"

You'll see the Rule Set Builder template display that box. Notice that I've included the `id`, `isDeleted`, `isDirty` and `isSaving` properties to easily see the state of that record. I am also displaying the length of the `hasMany` relationship.

2. Click on the "*Remove*" link to destroy that record

As expected, the Rule Set box disappears and the length indicates that there are 0 rule sets. I am both using `removeObject` from the parent model and `destroyRecord` on the object I'm trying to delete, although I think Ember data should take care of that for me.

Notice that in the console I'm logging the `firstObject`, which weirdly enough appears to be there even when the `length` is 0. I don't know if this is related to what happens in the next step.

3. Click on the "*New Rule Set*" link again

You'll see that two boxes are displayed. The first one is the rule set that you had previously deleted. Notice how it `isDeleted`, not `isDirty` and not `isSaving`, which as indicated [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isDeleted) means that the change has persisted.

Obviously hitting "*Remove*" again from the `isDeleted` record throws an error in the console saying:

> Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on  while in state root.deleted.saved.

What am I missing? Is `{{#each}}` supposed to show records that `isDeleted`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you experiencing this with a real adapter or only with the fixture adapter?

Comment: I am experiencing it with `ActiveModelAdapter`. I have a Rails API that shows the `DELETE` request and responds with no errors. My DB shows that the record is no longer there, the Ember inspector doesn't show the `rule-set` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted an issue in the Ember Data repo and it turns out that this has been reported already.

Take a look at [#2666](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2666) for follow-up and some ways to get around it for now.
The latest one I saw was posted by **dwickern** and it involves using a computed property instead

```
comments: Ember.computed.filterBy('model.comments', 'isDeleted', false)
```

Apparently **ember-data.1.0.0.beta-12** doesn't have the problem and there is already a [Pull Request #2722](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2722) with a possible solution.

Comment: it sounded like a bug.. gj